# Language D ; structs, immutable data and weird error

Tags: immutability, d

I'm learning language D. My first try is a simple 2d Vector that I can add, substract, dot product, etc...
I have this error when I try to compile:

Error :

> Error: (Vector2d __ctmp1245 = *D4math2v28Vector2d6*_initZ;
>    , __ctmp1245).this(this._x / l,this._y / l) is not mutable

Note : The error is related to Vector2d.dir()

The code is :

```
import std.math;
public struct Vector2d {

private const real _x;
private const real _y;

this(in real x, in real y) {
    _x = x; _y = y;
}

// Basic Properties ***************************************

@property const real X () { return _x; }

@property const real Y () { return _y; }

@property const real length () { return sqrt(_x*_x + _y*_y); }

// Operations ***************************************   

/**
* Define Equality 
*/
const bool opEquals(ref const Vector2d rhs) {
    return  approxEqual(_x, rhs._x) &&  approxEqual(_y, rhs._y);
}

/**
* Define unary operators + and - (+v)
*/
ref Vector2d opUnary(string op)() const
    if (op == "+" || op == "-")
{
    return Vector2d(mixin(op~"_x"), mixin(op~"_y"));
}

/**
* Define binary operator + and - (v1 + v2)
*/
ref Vector2d opBinary(string op) (ref const Vector2d rhs)
    if (op == "+" || op == "-")
{
    return Vector2d(mixin("_x" ~ op ~ "rhs._x"),mixin("_y" ~ op ~ "rhs._y"));
}

/**
* Scalar multiplication & division (v * 7)
*/
ref Vector2d opBinary(string op) (ref const real rhs) const
    if (op == "*" || op == "/")
{
    return Vector2d(mixin("_x" ~ op ~ "rhs"),mixin("_y" ~ op ~ "rhs"));
}

/**
* Dot Product (v1 * v2)
*/
ref real opBinary(string op) (ref const Vector2d rhs) const
    if (op == "*") {
        return _x*rhs._x + _y*rhs._y;
} 

/**
* Obtain the director vector of this vector.
*/
ref Vector2d dir() const {
    auto l = this.length();
    return Vector2d(_x / l, _y /l);
}

/**
* Obtains the projection of this vector over other vector
* Params:
*   b = Vector over project this vector
*/
ref Vector2d projectOnTo(in Vector2d b) const {
    return  b.dir() * (this * b.dir());
}

    }
```

I don't understand why I have this error. Plus  I try to change Type Qualifiers unsuccessful.
Even  I get the same error if i try this :

```
    ref Vector2d dir() const {
    auto l = this.length();
    return Vector2d(2,3);
 }
```

---

**EDIT :**

I tried removing "const" from attributes and removing "ref" from Dot product (I get a advice that not was lvalue) . The error is now this :

> src/math/v2.d(82): Error: this.opBinary(b.dir()) is not an lvalue

The line 82 is :

```
return  b.dir() * (this * b.dir());
```

---

**AutoANSWER:**

I fixed the last error, I changed ProjectOnTo
 to this :

```
ref Vector2d projectOnTo(in Vector2d b) const {
    auto a = this * b.dir();
    return  b.dir() * a;
}
```

Plus I run a unit test and looks that Vector2d It's doing ok.

So, finally I know now that I can't use immutable variables for a struct attributes, but I dont understand why.

Comment: can you try dropping the `ref` in the return type?

Comment: Which compiler do you use, by the way?

Comment: @xs0, dropping **ref** really helps, but... it looks like a compiler bug, a few lines before there is **ref** and no complaints...

Comment: that's because the compiler only does syntax control on templates (including the operator overloading functions) if you add a `unittest{Vector2d v;v+v;}` it will complain about it then

Comment: @xs0 Removing "ref" and "const" from dir() not changes any thing, same error.

Comment: @vines I'm using dmd 2.052 in Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: check my edit for a better fix than temp values all over the place

Comment: Regarding your first edit, D doesn't allow temporaries to be passed as a const ref parameter. IIRC Andrei thinks it was a bad decision to allow that in C++. Don't remember why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drop off the `const` qualifiers of the fields

```
public struct Vector2d {

    private real _x;
    private real _y;

    this(in real x, in real y) {
        _x = x; _y = y;
    }
    //...
```

the `const` is unnecessary and it will block you from simple assignment:

```
Vector2d v;
v = Vector2d(0,0);
```

this wont wont compile

and do remember that generic functions (the `opBinary` and `opUnary`) are only tested on syntax when they are parsed not on correctness of the code (your `opUnary` returns a `Vector!T` but the `T` generic type is never declared (and thus undefined) yet this passes compilation...)

---

edit I've made my own struct with operator overloads and except for `opCmp` and `opEquals` I don't use `ref const` for parameters just `const` (`in` works just as well for this)

**edit2** I've found it easiest to understand structs as groups of variables that can be declared, assigned and used at the same time with a few extra functions defined around the group of vars

so `Vector2D v;` in your original code would then be translated as `const real v__x; const real v__y;` the assignment `v = Vector(0,0);` would then be (after inlining the constructor) translated as `v__x = 0;v__y = 0;`

but as v__x is declared as `const` this wont be allowed

Comment: Wops! Vector!T come from a previus version taht I made that was more generic, workin wich Vectors of N-dimensions. I droped these generic, because I was getting anoyed wich these error. Thanks

Comment: @zardoz check my edits for a bit more info about why it fails

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to rewrite the body of `dir()` as

```
Vector2d v = Vector2d(0, 0);
return v;
```

and saw a nice error message then:

> vector2D.d(67): Error: variable vector2D.Vector2d.dir.v cannot modify struct with immutable members
>   vector2D.d(67): Error: escaping reference to local variable v

I don't understand how a variable could modify a struct, but this gave me the hint: why did you define _x and _y as **const**? I've removed the **const** from their declarations, and it has compiled :)